# using jsonp in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jsonp

I have the following javascript to get some jsonp into my webpage.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function updateSales(sales) {

         alert(sales);


     }


     function handleRefresh() {
         alert("I'm alive");

         var url = "http://172.18.4.8:83/webservice.asmx/ADUsers2?callback=updateSales";
         var newScriptElement = document.createElement("script");
         newScriptElement.setAttribute("src", url);
         newScriptElement.setAttribute("id", "jsonp");

         var oldScriptElement = document.getElementById("jsonp");
         var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
         if (oldScriptElement == null) {
             head.appendChild(newScriptElement);
         } else {
             head.replaceChild(newScriptElement, oldScriptElement);
         }

     }

    function pageLoad() {


       setInterval(handleRefresh, 3000);

    }
</script>
```

For some reason I can't get it to work.  I know the jsonp that I am getting is correct because I can browse to that url and I get the json format string.  When I load the webpage the I'm alive alert comes up fine every 3 seconds but I never get the alert with the webservice string.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Is content(script) is loading?

Comment: didn't catch that? the script has to be loading because I get the i'm alive alert.

Comment: You can check your page using developer tools since. you are adding a script in head you can check if content of script is loaded or not.

Comment: I believe the error is because my jsonp output is putting <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://172.18.4.8:83/WebService.asmx"> before the data.  When I run the developer tools in ie9, i get an error on the first line which is <?xml version="1.0" enconding="utf-8"

Comment: Use chrome developer tools. there you can check loaded content easly

Comment: I was able to get my webservice to responde with the correct fromat {"username":"carlos"}, however when I run my debugging tools I get an error saying Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: Please let us know how you fixed it, so a future user can benefit from your solution.

Comment: I haven't resolved the issue.

Comment: Did you already (i) decorate your Webservice with the [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] attribute, (ii) decorate your Webmethod with the [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] and (iii) have the httphandlers in your web.config setup to redirect the *.asmx call ?